# Application using Kinect doesn't work without Kinect studio installed

Tags: installation, kinect, kinect-sdk

I've written an application using the Kinect. It works great on my laptop when I wrote it but when I install a published version on a different PC it crashes. I've installed the Kinect Studio v2.0 and it seems to work fine now. I've also tried it with a Kinect Sensor attached before I installed the Kinect studio and it also didn't work. Installer worked on a different computer with Kinect studio installed.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I do not think this issue can be related to Kinect Studio. Instead you should check if the SDK is correctly installed or not...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when you connect the Kinect it installs some software, without this software the application crashes. The Kinect studio is not needed, the kinect just didn't install it's software the first time for some reason.